# Как сделать проверку перед добавлением SQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Какой есть пример в SQL, чтобы не добавлять с таблицу одинаковые значения?
Столбец уникален, при добавлении дубликата возникает ошибка:

```
mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'test' for key 'first_table'
```

где ttt - название таблицы, first_table - название столбца, test - значение.
SQL запрос:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO ttt(first_table, second_table) VALUES(%s, %s)"
mycursor.execute(sql, [test, a])
```

Как сделать проверку перед добавлением, нет ли в этом столбце уже это значение и не добавлять всю строку?

Comment: `insert ignore into ttt ...` и никаких проверок не нужно. это подавит ошибку дублирования, запись разумеется останется одна

Answer (score 0):

`insert ignore into ttt ...` и никаких проверок не нужно. это подавит ошибку дублирования, запись разумеется останется одна